# Inside the abstractmap class, why remove() does not show UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I was reading code of `[AbstractMap][1]` and I saw that

```
 public V More ...put(K key, V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

put() method throws an exception.

While remove() has a big implementation . And does not throws this exception.

Can somebody explain why so bias?

Comment: You cannot create an AbstractMap, only a sub-class which will override these methods.

Comment: The "bias" is that `remove` _can_ be implemented in terms of the other operations, and `put` cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `remove` operation just iterates over the entry set instead of being clever. `remove` can "always" <sup>1</sup> be implemented this way, even if it's painfully slow.

`put` always needs to know precise implementation details, including if the map is modifiable.

For unmodifiable maps the iterator wouldn't support `remove`, although this seems unbalanced.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is only true if the iterator supports remove, as the docs state.

Answer (score 1):

The `AbstractMap` class was designed to be a base for both read-write and read-only maps.

The getter must be implemented, so the implementation uses the abstract method `entrySet`. However, `put` may remain unimplemented if the map is read-only. The documentation says:

> To implement a modifiable map, the programmer must additionally override this class's `put` method (which otherwise throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`), and the iterator returned by `entrySet().iterator()` must additionally implement its `remove` method.

Note that the designers could have left the `put` method unimplemented, requiring programmers to override it explicitly. However, all read-only implementations would have to supply the same implementation (i.e. throwing the `UnsupportedOperationException`), so the designers opted to place this implementation into the shared code base.

The `remove` method, on the other hand, can be implemented in terms of the existing operations that the derived class must implement, so the implementation in the Java library is non-empty. It makes an assumption that the `entrySet().iterator()` implements its `remove` - if it does not, `AbstractMap`'s remove would throw whatever exception that the iterator's `remove` throws, presumably the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: @Thinker Presumably the iterator wouldn't support `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

```
" If such an entry is found, its value is
 * obtained with its <tt>getValue</tt> operation, the entry is removed
 * from the Collection (and the backing map) with the iterator's
 * <tt>remove</tt> operation, and the saved value is returned."
```

See what it says is the remove operation take place via Iterator remove operation. I suppose in case the underlying Map implementation is immutable it will throw unsupportedexception from its iterator remove method.